# Package conflict when compiling a Java 9 module

Tags: java, java-9, spring-cloud-feign, java-platform-module-system, java-module

I am trying to compile a simple module with a single direct dependency and I am getting many errors about packages that are read from 2 libraries.
I am using the latest stable version of the libraries and I see that the package is split between them.

Is there any way to solve the issue without waiting for a new version of the libraries with the package unsplit?

module-info.java:

```
module abc {
    requires spring.cloud.starter.feign;
}
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
dependencies {
    api 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-feign:1.3.4.RELEASE'
}
```

Java version: 9+181
gradle version: 4.2

./gradlew Abc:compileJava

> > Task :Abc:compileJava
> >     error: the unnamed module reads package com.netflix.ribbon from both ribbon and ribbon.transport
> >     error: the unnamed module reads package com.netflix.loadbalancer from both ribbon.httpclient and ribbon.loadbalancer
> >     error: the unnamed module reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
> >     error: the unnamed module reads package org.apache.commons.logging.impl from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
> >     error: the unnamed module reads package com.netflix.client.http from both ribbon.httpclient and ribbon.core
> >     error: the unnamed module reads package com.netflix.client from both ribbon.loadbalancer and ribbon.core
> >     error: module spring.cloud.starter.archaius reads package com.netflix.ribbon from both ribbon and ribbon.transport
> >     error: module spring.cloud.starter.archaius reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
> >     error: module spring.cloud.starter.archaius reads package org.apache.commons.logging.impl from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
> >     error: module spring.cloud.starter.archaius reads package com.netflix.loadbalancer from both ribbon.httpclient and ribbon.loadbalancer
> >     ...
> >     100 errors

Comment: In my case I only depend directly on a single library which I don't control, so I might have to tailor it by excluding the conflicting libs and include them back , merged. Ugly but might work...

Comment: Ya probably a tougher way, but futuristic in terms of migration to newer java version.

Comment: Or I'll just wait for the library maintainer to provide a compliant version...